# How to recover committed changes git Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

I committed changes to a local git repository today in Xcode so that I could go back to an older version. The newly committed changes from today are not showing up in the source control tab within Xcode; however, when I navigate to the .git folder in Finder, I can see the commit message in the COMMIT_EDITMSG file. This leads me to believe the commit did work, but for some reason Xcode isn't recognizing it. Is there any way to manually recover those committed changes from Finder if Xcode won't recognize them?

Comment: Don't use Xcode's Git-related features. They pretty much suck (except for the change bars which are super-helpful). Look at your repository through the command line.

Comment: I use Xcode for a lot of git related features. It's 95% reliable. When it's not I usually end up just killing and relaunching Xcode. However, to be sure you've actually made the commits you think you did, just do `git log` in terminal and see if it's there. You might be on a wrong branch or may not actually have those commits at all. You can also do `git reflog`. `git log` is good for seeing the history of _a branch_. `git reflog` is good for _seeing history of checked out branches/commits/tags across your your project_

Comment: Like @matt said, I would highly recommend using the command line rather than Xcode's git features. 

I would even take that a step further and say don't use ANY code editor's features for git because you really don't know what they are actually doing. 

When you commit and you want to see if it was executed correctly, I would use `git log` and `git diff <your main branch>` from your command line to see the commit and the changes you have made respectively.

Comment: To be able to answer your question, we need clarification on what you mean by "recover". Are your changes not showing up in Xcode? When you commit the head of your branch should be moved to the new commit so you shouldn't have to "recover" your changes or do anything to access them in any way since they are already accessible unless you have committed on top of that. If that is the case then all you have to do is `git reset head~` and use the `--hard` flag if you don't want the changes from the previous commit anymore.

Comment: @Jake I committed the changes and then went back to an older commit on the same branch (undo of sorts to figure some things out). I definitely went through the process of committing, including adding the notes, before going to check out the older commit. I'll check out using the command line and see where I get! Assuming the commit DOES exist, how would one go about checking that out in the current instance of Xcode through the command line? Or is that not really possible? Still learning all of this, so I appreciate the help!

Comment: I was able to find the "address" of the commit I was looking for through the command line, but what's at that address is still a mystery. I think I just need to figure out how to get that back into Xcode... maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @Razorback2424 ah that makes sense. How you recover your changes depends on how you "went back". What command did you do to accomplish that exactly? Git makes changes directly to the directory that your repository is in and Xcode will reflect that if they are the same directory so you shouldn't have any trouble with Xcode picking up those changes if they are restored correctly with git.